# How to add an existing project in WEB IDE to the Git?

Tags: git, sapui5, sap-web-ide

How is it possible to add an existing SAPUI5 application inside of the WEB IDE to the Git?

Is it possible to connect it to the Github also or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add an existing project in WebIDE to the git repository.
To do this, right click on the project & click on Git > Initialize Local Repository.

[image]

This will initialize a local Repository for your project.

The Git pane on the right provides you with all git actions like commit, push, clone among others.
[image]

You can also push your code to Github by adding a remote. 
For this, right click on your project & click on Git > Set Remote. Here you should provide the HTTPS Url of you remote Github repository. After this you will have to provide your Github credentials to authenticate.
[image]

Once you have your remote repository set, you can push/pull your code to your remote from the Git Pane.

Comment: The problem is that I did the same steps as you described, (forget the github for now) then I made a git repository in HCP, and wanted to add it as the remote to this project. I could add it without any error also. But when I want to push to the remote branch, it does not show the master branch of the remote.

Comment: @Martin When you initialized the local repository do not commit. First add the remote branch from HCP git repository and then commit and push, then the problem that you mentioned will be solved.

Comment: @Martin Also it is very important to tick the item `create empty commit` checkbox when you are creating a git repository inside of HCP, otherwise you don't have master branch inside of your repository. Then when you are trying to push data to remote repository there is no branch to push data to that branch.